# Fuzzy clustering without number of clusters

Tags: cluster-analysis

I'm looking for fuzzy clustering algorithm which does not need specified number of clusters. I used hierarchical clustering but it gives results of "hard" clusters. I need something similar but with possibility that one element can be in more than one cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I searched google about it some days ago, it is HFRECCA. I know about FRECCA, but i don't know details about HFRECCA. You can get it from here- http://www.researchgate.net/publication/261081980_Text_Clustering_Using_HFRECCA_and_Rough_K-Means_Clustering_Algorithm